# Unique decoding

Tags: coding-theory

Suppose that we have a block code $C$ which has unique decoding, meaning that for all words $x$ (not necessarily in the code) there exists a unique word $c$ in the code with minimum distance (i.e. the other words in $C$ are at distance strictly greater than $c$ from $x$).

I want to know if under this condition the code is a Hamming code, i.e. the Hamming bound is attained.

Comment: _"a Hamming code, i.e. the Hamming bound is attained"_ Some terminology issue here. A code where "the Hamming bound is attained" is not a Hamming code, but a "perfect code". (Hamming codes happen to be perfect codes, but that's other thing)

Comment: Sorry - I meant a perfect code, not a Hamming code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a rather trivial counterxample, consider some perfect code, and augment it by adding a `0` in the last position.

Comment: Very nice counterexample. Thanks a lot.